# HANA used memory greater than licensed one

Tags: hana

I have a SAP HANA Server which has a physical memory of **128 GB** but licensed for **16 GB**. The total memory used shows **22 GB** which is larger than the licensed amount. How is that possible? I have only one Columnar Table which is **3 GB** in the database. Could anyone explain this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is twofold:
1. Not all licenses are enforced. Specifically not based on the memory used. However of the license dialogue window shows a higher memory usage than licensed, you breach the license.

2. Licensed memory is not directly checked against the used memory in the mem. Overview. Instead an internal calculation takes a timeframe into consideration.

For your example, it's not just your table in memory, but also HANA internal tables, memory used for query processing, session management etc.

For a broader understanding of how memory management works in HANA and how to interprete the memory usage statistics correctly, please see the admin/operations guide. The SAP Community Network also has a number of resources and discussions on that. scn.sap.com

Comment: @ Lars Br. I went through the discussions of the licensed memory and i found I can keep a global allocation limit.But still I am not sure the licensed memory will be checked against the database resident memory or system resident memory? Could you help me out?Thanks in advance